# How does noNameFunc1 truly work here and how can I pass values to it?

Tags: c

I have this code for finding the factorial of a number, and there's an implicitly declared function noNameFunc2 in the return value of the first function noNameFunc1.
How can I pass values to the first function without running into the error: undefined reference to `noNameFunc2'?

All I'm trying to understand is how control is being passed between the two functions.

I pass values to noNameFunc2() and it works as it should. noNameFun1() is really just a check for whether input is 0 or nah.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int noNameFunc1(int);
int noNameFunc2(int, int);
int main() {
    int noNameFunc1(int n){
        if (n==0){
            return 1;
        }
        return noNameFunc2(n, 1);       
    }

    int noNameFunc2(int c, int s) {
        if (c == 1) {
            return s;
    }   else {
            return noNameFunc2(c - 1, s * c);
        }
    }
    printf("%d", noNameFunc2(5,1));
return 0;
}
```

If I edit the printf statement to printf("%d", noNameFunc1(5)); there's an error: undefined reference to `noNameFunc2'
Why does this crop up and can I pass values to noNameFunc1() at all?

Comment: you cant define a function within another function in standard c, define them outside the main

Comment: Its not a good practice to define a function `noNameFunc1()` inside another function `main()` in C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference error to function that is actually defined in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358341/undefined-reference-error-to-function-that-is-actually-defined-in-c)

Comment: Since the functions are not mutually recursive, and since function 2 only calls itself, you can define 2 before 1 inside main and it should work — and you could then delete the declarations outside of main.  But you shouldn't be messing with nested functions unless you know what you're doing — they're non-standard and therefore not recommended for portable code.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the functions inside `main`. This is an example of **nested functions**.

These are not allowed in the C standard, but some compilers offer it as a GCC-compatible extension (so GCC provides them, and so does Clang).

What you should do is to have the function definition outside of the `main` function. This will allow both functions to be seen by the compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int noNameFunc1(int);
int noNameFunc2(int, int);

int noNameFunc1(int n){
    if (n==0){
        return 1;
    }
    return noNameFunc2(n, 1);       
}

int noNameFunc2(int c, int s) {
    if (c == 1) {
        return s;
}   else {
        return noNameFunc2(c - 1, s * c);
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("%d", noNameFunc2(5,1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assumed that the function prototypes would be copied by OP. Adding it to clear confusion now.